# Jquery validate plugin alphanumeric method with acceptance of dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a requirement in a username field where I have to validate the special characters but allow '.' dot character.
We have custom method in plugin alphanumeric but it doesn't allow dot. please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsAKx/328/)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and . only please");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this regex `/^[\w.]+$/i`

You can use character set `[]` of regex to select multiple character.

`^` in regex means it starts matching from the start of the string.

`\w` in regex means it accepts all **alpha Numeric `(A-Za-z0-9)`** and **underscore (_).**

I have added `.` inside the character set to allow character `.` also.

You can add more character inside the `[]` character set to allow them too.

`+` in the regex means it will keep on matching all the character in the string.

`$` in regex means it will check till the end of the line if its multi-line

`i` in regex is a flag that says its case insensitive.

Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YsAKx/330/

**Updated JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\w.]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                alphanumeric: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: what If I want to allow underscore as well ?

Comment: `\w` in `/^[\w.]+$/i` will take care of underscore

Comment: /^[\w.]+$/i this regex didn't take care of underscore

Comment: add _ inside the character set. Use this `/^[\w._]+$/i` regex

Comment: This does not seem to match for dots (.) which is strange my test string is "The Test . Is a new" in chrome and Firefox

Comment: @StephenSenkomagoMusoke  You need to allow space inside the character set as your test string contains [space] "The Test . Is a new"  which breaks the regex '+'.
Use this regex to allow space `/^[\w .]+$/i`